# JQuery-Ajax programming with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I an new to jquery and trying to integrate My MVC Controller with Jquery-Ajax. But is not working properly. Please check with below code.

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Shared/_Layout.cshtml(body section)

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/Scripts/AjaxProgramming.js"></script>
</body>
```

Controllers/AjaxProgrammingController.cs

```
public class AjaxProgrammingController : Controller
    {
        MVCClassesProjectEntities2 mcpe = new MVCClassesProjectEntities2();

        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            Response.Write("Index action method processed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetEmpData(int id)
        {
            Employee empDetails = mcpe.Employees.Find(id);
            return Json(empDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Scripts/AjaxProgramming.js

```
function fn_getEmp()
{
    var Id = $("#txtEmpId").val();

    $.ajax
    ({
        cache: false, 
        url: "/AjaxProgramming/GetEmpData/" + Id, 
        type: "GET", 
        data: "", 
        contentType: "application/json;",
        success: function (response)
        {
            var empList = "EmpName : " + response.EmpName + "<br>";
            empList += "Job : " + response.Job + "<br>";
            empList += "Salary : " + response.Salary + "<br>";
            empList += "DeptNo : " + response.DeptNo + "<br>";
            $("#spnStatus").html(empList);
        }
    });
}
```

Views/Home.cshtml

```
Enter Employee number : <input type="text" id="txtEmpId" name="txtEmpId" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" id="btnDetails" name="btnDetails" value="Get Emp Details" onclick="fn_getEmp()"/><br /><br />
<span id="spnStatus"></span>
```

when i click the button i am not getting the result. Please help me.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Is the `GetEmpData()` method being hit. You need to provide some more details

Comment: use debugger to check whether the method is being hit  , if not then check the `RouteConfig` in `AppStart`

Comment: i am not getting in any error and not getting result also.

Comment: Then debug your script!

Comment: I dont know how to debug the script.. can you help me please

Comment: You should not be writing javascript/jquery if you do't know how to debug it. For Chrome, [start here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: Are you even sure that your Javascript function fn_getEmp is getting called? the way you do it, through onclick probably works, but is a wrong way to go. I am not trying to be rude or anything, but you are not yet ready to write ajax calls in jquery. Good luck - we've all been there! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I am reading the question is that the ajax call never gets to GetEmpData() method. I would say that either /AjaxProgramming/GetEmpData/5 is not routed to the right controller, or the parameter does not match what's in the route, or something similar.

As @Stephen Muecke suggested, first thing is to test your JavaScript portion. Do you see it in F12 tools. If you do - what's the error code. If it's 500, what's the returned XML. If these three questions sound unclear to you - then you are not yet ready to write AJAX queries.

By the way, why are you using $.ajax call, rather than $.get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm passing id through data instead of passing url.

Try below ajax code.

```
 $.ajax
      ({
          cache: false,
          url: "/AjaxProgramming/GetEmpData/",
          type: "GET",
          data: { id: Id },
          contentType: "application/json;",
          success: function (response) {
          var empList = "EmpName : " + response.EmpName + "<br>";
                        empList += "Job : " + response.Job + "<br>";
                        empList += "Salary : " + response.Salary + "<br>";
                        empList += "DeptNo : " + response.DeptNo + "<br>";
                        $("#spnStatus").html(empList);
          }
       });
```